# Why am i getting '500 (Internal Server Error jQuery.min.js:4) ' error in the following ajax code?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, ajaxform

I am trying to login the user by opening the bootstrap login modal and filling it with username and password but the movement i hit 'Login' button i get the following error message in the browser's console:

[image: 500 (internal server error)]

**ajax:**

```
$('#loginForm').on('submit',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/librarysystem/login/",
    data: {
      'username':$("username").val(),
      'password':$("password").val(),
      csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
      if (data.response) {
        alert("Invalid");
      }  
      else
        alert("Valid");
   }        
  });
});
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^register/$',views.create_user),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name="Index"),
    url(r'^validate/$',views.validateForm),
    url(r'^article/$', views.article, name="Article"),
    url(r'^Login/$',views.loginUser, name="Login")
]
```

**views.py:**

```
from forms import signupForm
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.models import User    

def loginUser(request):
    data = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
       username = request.POST['username']
       password = request.POST['password']
       user = authenticate(username=username,password=password);                
       if user is None:
            data['response'] = False
       else:
            data['response'] = True
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

Post more info about error response would be helpful, like

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/librarysystem/login/",
    data: {
      //...
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
      //...
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, status, err){
        alert(jqXHR.responseText);
    }
  });
```

BTW, I'm just guessing the exception may be raised by authentication setting of Django was not properly configured.

Comment: Maybe yes this is want i get in password field of every user in Django admin interface https://postimg.org/image/y9nz2vitz/

Comment: Where did the users come from? If they're created by your own admin form, make sure `user.set_password` is called in `save` method.

Comment: Here is my form for registration and login ->  forms.py: https://postimg.org/image/4tccpx7b3/ and here is my registration view: https://postimg.org/image/xf1p1rsb5/  where should i use 'user.set_password' ? as you can see i don't use save method in registration form instead i use 'create' to create and save user.

Comment: okay i fixed the problem of invalid password like this : https://postimg.org/image/jgd33zh9v/  by using 'create_user' method instead of simple 'create' method but if i again try to register the same user it should display an error that i have created but instead of that i get "POST 500 internel server error" in the console. doesn't 'create_user' method return None if it founds user i already registered ???

Comment: After hashing the password i still get the same '500 internal server error' here is the details of it: https://postimg.org/image/q2jpk52z7/

Answer (score 0):

Change following 2 lines

```
username = request.POST['username']
password = request.POST['password']
```

to

```
username = request.POST.get('username','')
password = request.POST.get('password','')
```

Comment: okay that solved the problem but it prints 'Valid' for every input even if i give username and password of someone who doesn't exist in the database.

Comment: i printed the return value of authenticate and returns none for all users including those who don't exist in the database. what is wrong

Comment: leave it i fixed the problem :)